# AddQueryOption not working in WCF DataServices Portable

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

I have created a Xamarin.Forms project and now I intend to consume some data from a WCF Data Service.

I create the query like this:

```
        MyEntities entities = new MyEntities(new Uri("http://localhost/MyService.svc/"));
        DataServiceQuery<MyServiceReference.Info> query = entities.CreateQuery<MyServiceReference.Info>("GetInfo");            
        query.AddQueryOption("infoTag", "abc");
        query.BeginExecute((result) =>
        {
            try
            {
                var que = result.AsyncState as DataServiceQuery<MyServiceReference.Info>;
                var res = que.EndExecute(result);
                foreach (var item in res)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.Name);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }, query);
```

According to [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2010/07/06/custom-query-options-on-the-wcf-data-services-client.aspx), I should see the complete query along with the parameters.

When I check the query URI, it is this: `http://localhost/MyService.svc/GetInfo`

It seems that the parameters are missing.

How could I add them properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out...
I like Fluent syntax very much but I forgot to check if `CreateQuery` uses that.

So instead of

```
query.AddQueryOption("infoTag", "abc");
```

I have to use this:

```
 query=query.AddQueryOption("infoTag", "abc");
```

or this:

```
DataServiceQuery<MyServiceReference.Info> query = entities.CreateQuery<MyServiceReference.Info>("GetInfo").AddQueryOption("infoTag", "abc");
```